# multiple zabbix agent on linux (centos)

Tags: linux, alert, monitoring, zabbix

Multiple zabbix agent can be easily installed on windows system like this

```
zabbix_agentd.exe --config <configuration_file_for_instance_1> --install --multiple-agents
zabbix_agentd.exe --config <configuration_file_for_instance_2> --install --multiple-agents
...
zabbix_agentd.exe --config <configuration_file_for_instance_N> --install --multiple-agents
```

You can find more details on [zabbix official documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/appendix/install/windows_agent) I have tried and It is working perfectly.

But, I could not find any documentation on multiple linux agents. Even I could not found any info whether it is possible or not.

I have tried running zabbix_agentd with same parameters(--install --multiple-agents) on linux. But these parameters are not valid on linux system. Or any other similar parameter exists.

So, basicly is it possible to run multiple agent on linux environment(especially centos)? And, if it is possible how?

Comment: It is possible - you simply specify different configuration files that specify different PID files, log files, ports to listen on, etc. What problem do you experience with this setup?

Comment: If I changed pid file path in zabbix_agentd.conf, Is it required to create a file on that path, or is it going to be generated automatically ?

Comment: A PID file is created automatically by Zabbix agent when it starts and contains the PID of the main process. Scripts use this information to stop the currently running agent. When Zabbix agent is stopped, the PID file is automatically removed.

Comment: I have tried and it worked. thanks. Can you repost these as an answer. So I can accept it.

Comment: Sure, thank you! Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. One should simply specify different configuration files that specify different PID files, log files, ports to listed on, etc., so that agents do not conflict with one another, similar to how you would do it on Windows.

In particular, in Unix there is a concept of a PID file. A PID file is created automatically by Zabbix agent when it starts and contains the PID of the main process. Scripts use this information to stop the currently running agent. When Zabbix agent is stopped, the PID file is automatically removed.